# Error "undefined reference to xercesc_2_7"

Tags: command-line, compiling, make

I've been trying to install SUMO and only recently got the ./configure to make all of the files; but, when I try to 'make' it gives the [all-recursive error 1:

```
../utils/xml/libxml.a(SUMOSAXAttributesImpl_Xerces.o): In function `SUMOSAXAttributesImpl_Xerces::getFloat(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
SUMOSAXAttributesImpl_Xerces.cpp:(.text+0x9ff): undefined reference to `xercesc_2_7::XMLString::transcode(char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [netgen] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads/sumo-0.12.3/src/netgen'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads/sumo-0.12.3/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Do you have any idea to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: The error is "undefined reference to `xercesc_2_7", "Error “[Install-recursive] Error 1” is a result of that ;) And it seems you are missing a lib

Answer (score 1):

It's actually failing to link to the Xerces library. You [need to tell it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719927/undefined-reference-to-xercesc-2-8-when-compiling-sample-ocde) what to look for with the `-l` argument and where to look with `-L`.

```
g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -L/usr/lib -o xercesTest xercesTest.cpp -lxerces-c
```

Obviously you also need the library present:

```
sudo apt-get install libxerces-c-dev
```

Comment: i already try to install libxerces but lock administration directory

root@rezekiekawaty:/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads# sudo apt-get install libxerces-c-dev
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @user283089 that one has been answered on AU several times ;) Like: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: i have to try install libxerces but still doesn't work :(
im'
SUMOSAXAttributesImpl_Xerces.cpp:(.text+0x9ff): undefined reference to `xercesc_2_7::XMLString::transcode(char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [netgen] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads/sumo-0.12.3/src/netgen'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads/sumo-0.12.3/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rezekiekawaty/Downloads/sumo-0.12.3/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1